# NULL Value in Email Launcher

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I read data from firestore and use it for url launcher for email. But the value that i get when prompt open email is NULL. But it not prompt any error.

My code to set data into var listed.

```
var userName, userAdd, userAge, userResult, uniEmail;

void emailDetail() async{
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new StreamBuilder(
          stream: UniQuery().getUserDetail(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return new Text('Loading..... Please wait');

            var userDocument = snapshot.data;
             userName = userDocument['name'];
             userAge = userDocument['age'];
             userAdd = userDocument['address'];
             userResult= userDocument['result'];

             return new Text('Success read user data');
          }
      );
  }
}

void emailAddress() async{
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new StreamBuilder(
          stream: UniQuery().getUniBasedSelectedUni(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return new Text('Loading..... Please wait');

            var userDocument = snapshot.data;
            uniEmail = userDocument['email'];

            return new Text('Success read university email');
          }
      );
  }
}

void sendEmail() async {
  emailDetail();
  emailAddress();
  var url = 'mailto:$uniEmail?subject= University Application'
      +'&body= Name: $userName \nAge: $userAge \nAddress: $userAdd'
      +'\nResult: $userResult';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  }
  else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Code use to get data from firestore for user detail and sender email address

```
   Future<String> getCurrentUser() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uID = user.uid.toString();
    return uID;
  }

  setUserDetail() async{
    userID = await getCurrentUser();
  }

  getUserDetail(){
    setUserDetail();
    return dbReference.collection('User')
        .document(userID)
        .snapshots();
  }

  getUniBasedSelectedUni(){
    return dbReference.collection('University')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: selectedUni)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

and i call it the sendEmail here

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[

        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          onPressed:(){
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)
            => mainmenu()));
          },
        ),

        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
          onPressed: (){
            sendEmail();
          }
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image: NULL Value]

Comment: Have you tried to await: `await setUserDetail()`?

Comment: i didnt but that function i call on other method.. and it works fine

Comment: any idea how to fix this? i confuse already

Comment: I am sorry, no idea